# Error: Could not find or load main class for cucumber and testNG

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng

I am trying to create a Selenium project with TestNG and Cucumber.
When I try to execute the test cases from Cucumber's Runner file or TestNG XML file, I am getting the below error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNGException
```

When I try to execute the test cases from Cucumber Feature file, I am getting the below error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

[image]
This is the structure of my project

RunnerClass:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/Administration/Export.feature"}, 
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/Destination"}, 
        glue = {"valveAware.port.localhost.tests"}
        )



public class ValveAwareRunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

TestNG XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="valveAware.port.localhost.runner.ValveAwareRunnerTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

.classpath file of the VATestProject:
[image]

jars added:
[image]

I am unable to identify the reason for the issue.

Comment: Is it a maven project ?

Comment: Its a Gradle Project but currently I am not bringing the dependencies through jar. I have added them manually.

Comment: @SameerArora - Any suggestions?

Comment: Check ur classpath. Use gradle to get dependencies.What happens when u execute the runner as TestNG test? U have 2 testng.xml in the project.

Comment: I checked the Project's .classpath file and it has testNG path. When I execute the runner file as TestNG, I get - Unable to initialize main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG. Also, when I had 1 testng.xml file, then also I was getting the same errors

Comment: @Grasshopper - attached the snapshot of classpath file as well

Comment: Remove cucumber-jvm-deps, cucumber-core and cucumber-junit jars. Add cucumber-testng jar

Comment: Doing that throws the compilation error in Cucumber Runner class for @CucumberOptions

Comment: Tried for removing the other 2 but still getting the same error. Added the snapshot for jars added.

Comment: @Grasshopper - can u suggest something?

Comment: Are u able to execute a simple TestNg test executing from xml or IDE? Without any selenium or cucumber.

Comment: No. Getting the same error

Comment: Classpath problem. Create a fresh new project and use Maven or Gradle to get the dependencies and check.

Comment: Your Suggestion helped @Grasshopper and it worked. Thanks!